# React Native Picker component with React hook: cannot pass value of Picker to parent

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm using the Picker component of React Native to make a selection. Unfortunately, it is not working; I cannot get the value of onValueChange to pass upwards to handleChangeCharacter.
Here is what I have so far:

```
  const [characterIndex, selectCharacter] = useState('0')

  const handleChangeCharacter = ({ e }) => {
    console.log('e', e)
    selectCharacter(e)
  }

  const cStyle = "Style: " + characters[characterIndex].cStyle
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Picker selectedValue={characterIndex} onValueChange={handleChangeCharacter}>
          {
            characters.map((character, index) => {
              return (
                <Picker.Item label={character.name} value={index} key={index} />
              )
            })
          }
        </Picker>
...
...
...
```

I'm using the React Hook to set the value of "characterIndex". Unfortunately, 'e' is always 'undefined.'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems okay. Can you give more context around how this component is used?

Comment: Certainly. I have an array of Character objects. The array's index is determined by the value selected in the Picker. (The values of the Picker are populated by the array.) So if you select "Bob", whose index is 1, it should display all the data for Character[1]. I've played around with this, but I can't seem to get the value of the Picker to pass upwards to the parent either.

Comment: I just figured out my problem.. I should be calling "HandleChangeCharacter" instead of the hook. I do that and the error goes away, but I still can't get "value" to pass upwards. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `handleChangeCharacter`, you are destructuring but the `onValueChange` doesn't pass object with property `e`. [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker#onvaluechange)

> onValueChange - Callback for when an item is selected. This is called with the following parameters:
>
> **itemValue**: the value prop of the item that was selected
>
> **itemPosition**: the index of the selected item in this picker

```
// remove destructuring
const handleChangeCharacter = (value, index) => {
  console.log('value', value, index) // equals to index which is set here value={index}
  selectCharacter(value)
}
```

Comment: You are amazing, my friend. Thank you!